# Variables vs. Constants, how are they defined in ZFC, and how they differ?

Tags: logic, set-theory, definition, axioms

The other day I was thinking that whenever I'm presented in Uni with constants my teachers use letters like $c$, $k$, $n$, $a$, $b$, etc, and when encountered with variables they use letters like $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$, etc. However, these are only labels, there's nothing stopping me from using $c$ as a variable, or $x$ a constant; this led me to ask myself how are constants vs. variables formally defined.

So far, I have only come up with the definition of a constant in a set by reading "Introduction to Set" Theory by Jech and Hrbáček:

[image]

According what they say, given a set $A$ and a $0$-ary operation $R$ on $A$, $(∅,a)$, such that $(∅,a)\in R$ and $a\in A$, is a constant and we can call it just $a$.

Nonetheless, I haven't found anything on the book about the formal definition of a variable.

Is my understanding of the definition of a constant correct? Do you know what's the definition of a variable? (if so, could you share it with me?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I disagree with the marking as duplicate; the concept of variables and constants is a different one in an equation (which is the context the other question asks about) than in logic. A constant in symbolic logic is a term whose reference which is fixed within one interpretation but can vary between different contexts; this comes close to what would be a parameter in an equation, whereas an equational constant such as $\pi$ has no real pendant in symbolic logic.

Answer (score 4):

"The" language of first-order logic, which ZFC is based on, is a family of languages.

- All languages share the same logical symbols:

  - individual variables: $x_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$
  - connectives: $\neg, \land, \lor, \to$
  - quantifiers: $\exists, \forall$
- and auxiliary symbols:

  - parentheses: $), ($
  - comma: $,$
- Different languages differ in their inventory of non-logical symbols:

  - individual constants
  - function symbols
  - predicate symbols

One defines a formal language by listing all members of each category.

For the language of ZFC, it is sufficient to limit oneself to:

- individual constants: none
- function symbols: none
- predicate symbols: $\in$

One can add some useful additional symbols, e.g. *

- individual constants: $\emptyset$
- function symbols: $\cap, \cup, \wp$
- predicate symbols: $\subset, \subseteq$

Variables and constants are thus defined extensionally by specifying which elements they encompass in a given language; but **there is no formal definition of the underlying *concept* of variables and constants**. Remember that variables and constants themselves are just *symbols*, not mathematical objects; and there are no global regulations on what these symbols need to look like. Though it makes sense in practice to stick to conventions, such as using $x, y, z$ (possibly with indices) for variables and $a, b, c, \ldots$ for constants.

Your understanding of a constant is not entirely correct, though the way it is presented in the text also makes it kind of difficult: We have constant/function/predicate *symbols* which are *interpreted* as elements/functions/relations on the domain. The object $a \in A$ would be the interpretation of a constant symbol such as $c$.
Which constants there exist is fixed by specifying the formal language; how they are interpreted is fixed by specifying a *structure* consisting of a domain of objects and an interpretation function which maps the constant/function/predicate symbols to elements/functions/relations on that domain. This interpretation again has to be defined by explicitly listing which formal symbols map to which object: $\mathcal{I}(c) = a$. **A constant is a symbol which by itself is meaningless; its meaning is given by fixing an interpretation which maps it to an element of the domain.**

The meaning of variables is given by an *assignment function* which maps each variable to an element of the domain; again, this assignment needs to be explicitly specified.
The difference between variables and constants is that a variable can undergo different assignments and thus take different values in the same structure under which the formula is evaluated, whereas the meaning of a constant is fixed within a structure.

---

* though typically these would not be treated as elementary symbols of the formal language whose interpretation needs to be specified in a structure, but rather as abbreviations for some complex expression, e.g. $y = \wp(x)$ is taken as shorthand for $\forall z (z \in y \leftrightarrow \forall u \in z (z \in x)))$ (meaning that the elements of $\wp(x)$ are exactly those sets all of whose members are elements of $x$).